# How magento does search functionality on grid columns data in magento backend

Tags: php, magento, grid

I am new to magento. I want to learn how magento filters grid column data internally. I am able to see the ajax call in the console log but am not getting the internal flow of the filter. Can anyone tell me the flow for filtering.